# CSS Flexbox Wrap - How to fill row before large item

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm not sure if that is possible. I probably would even call it unlikely. But I want to be sure.
My goal is to get an effect as the iTunes music player at the album cover view. Means I have a list of items with the same size that nicely wraps from line to line.

```
| A | | B | | C |
| D | | E | | F |
| G | | H |
```

This is just `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: space-around;` on the container. Now I want to conditionally render an additional component when one of the items get clicked. Let's say item B gets clicked, a "banner" Banner-B opens. this banner should take the full width, to wrap into the next row. **But** I would love to have the row where item B is, gets still fulled with smaller items until nothing fits into it anymore. So at the moment in looks like this:

```
  | A |   | B |
|    Banner-B   |
| C | | D | | E |
| F | | G | | H |
```

What I would like to make it render is like this:

```
| A | | B | | C |
|    Banner-B   |
| D | | E | | F |
| G | | H |
```

Any ideas how or if this is possible? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS grid can do it. An example using hover that you can easily change to be a click event

```css
.container {
   display:grid;
   grid-template-columns:repeat(3, 1fr);
   grid-auto-flow:dense; /* this will do all the magic */
   grid-gap:3px;
}

.container > div {
  padding:10px;
  border:2px solid red;
}

.container > section {
  grid-column:1 / -1; /* take full width */
  padding:20px;
  border:2px solid blue;
  display:none;
}
.container > div:hover + section {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div>A</div><section>Info A</section>
 <div>B</div><section>Info B</section>
 <div>C</div><section>Info C</section>
 <div>D</div><section>Info D</section>
 <div>E</div><section>Info E</section>
 <div>F</div><section>Info F</section>
 <div>G</div><section>Info G</section>
 <div>H</div><section>Info H</section>
 <div>I</div><section>Info I</section>
</div>
```

A `space-around` configuration with wrapping:

```css
.container {
   display:grid;
   grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fit, 150px);
   justify-content:space-around;
   grid-auto-flow:dense; /* this will do all the magic */
   grid-gap:3px;
}

.container > div {
  padding:10px;
  border:2px solid red;
}

.container > section {
  grid-column:1 / -1; /* take full width */
  padding:20px;
  border:2px solid blue;
  display:none;
}
.container > div:hover + section {
  display:block;
}

body {
 min-height:150vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div>A</div><section>Info A</section>
 <div>B</div><section>Info B</section>
 <div>C</div><section>Info C</section>
 <div>D</div><section>Info D</section>
 <div>E</div><section>Info E</section>
 <div>F</div><section>Info F</section>
 <div>G</div><section>Info G</section>
 <div>H</div><section>Info H</section>
 <div>I</div><section>Info I</section>
</div>
```

Also like below with an `auto-fill` configuration

```css
.container {
   display:grid;
   grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fill, minmax(150px,1fr));
   grid-auto-flow:dense; /* this will do all the magic */
   grid-gap:3px;
}

.container > div {
  padding:10px;
  border:2px solid red;
}

.container > section {
  grid-column:1 / -1; /* take full width */
  padding:20px;
  border:2px solid blue;
  display:none;
}
.container > div:hover + section {
  display:block;
}

body {
 min-height:150vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div>A</div><section>Info A</section>
 <div>B</div><section>Info B</section>
 <div>C</div><section>Info C</section>
 <div>D</div><section>Info D</section>
 <div>E</div><section>Info E</section>
 <div>F</div><section>Info F</section>
 <div>G</div><section>Info G</section>
 <div>H</div><section>Info H</section>
 <div>I</div><section>Info I</section>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay that is pretty cool. How would I make this dynamic so that the number of columns adopts automatically to the window width? :)

Comment: @weilbith added a second idea and a third one

Comment: Ah, one last question: before the left and right spacing of each row was equally distributed due to `justify-content: space-around`. Now it looks like `justify-content: flex-start`. Depending on the window width this looks quite ugly. Any idea how to resolve that? (I tried auto-padding for the container)

Comment: @weilbith you mean for the last row?